# Converting fractions to binary string?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

To convert an integer value, manually, to binary string you (one technique is  to) continuously divide by `2` till the quotient `> 0` and append the remainder in reverse order.

```
string decimalToBinary(int n)
{
    string binary = string.Empty;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        // get the LSB
        int remainder = n % 2;

        // truncate the LSB
        n /= 2;

        // insert remainder in front
        binary = remainder.ToString() + binary;
    }
    return binary;
}
```

However, I can't figure out how to convert a fraction (floating point number like for example `-0.30`), to binary string. More specifically what algorithm should I use. Could anyone suggest an idea?

Comment: So what are you stuck on?  Selecting a method or implementing it?  Are you familiar with how floating point numbers are represented in memory?  Have you tried taking the output of [`BitConverter.GetBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhwsaf3w(v=vs.110).aspx) and converting _that to binary?

Comment: How do you intend to represent a decimal value as a binary string?  How should e.g. 3.14 look in the binary representation you want to construct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To convert an integer value, manually

Note that since your input is a an integer which can be negative or zero. But your condition for the `while` loop is `while (n > 0)`

Therefore, your code right now cannot handle the situation when the input is `0` (it will return `string.Empty`) or negative (it will return nothing).

To fix it, you may consider to change your input to `uint` and make special case for `n == 0`:

```
string decimalToBinary(uint n) //note this uint
{
    if (n == 0) //special case
        return "0";

    string binary = string.Empty;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        // get the LSB
        uint remainder = n % 2;

        // truncate the LSB
        n /= 2;

        // insert remainder in front
        binary = remainder.ToString() + binary;
    }
    return binary;
}
```

Or you change it internally:

```
private string decimalToBinary(int n) {
    string binary = string.Empty;
    if (n == 0)
        return "0";
    uint p = (uint)n; //note this cast
    while (p > 0) {
        // get the LSB
        uint remainder = p % 2;

        // truncate the LSB
        p /= 2;

        // insert remainder in front
        binary = remainder.ToString() + binary;
    }
    return binary;
}
```

Then you should get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a C++ implementation for fraction to binary conversion:

```
double frac = .1;

int digits = 1, intpart;

cout <<".";

while (digits < 32 && frac != 0.)
{
    frac = frac * 2;

    intpart = frac;
    frac = frac - intpart;

    cout << intpart;

    digits++;
}
```

> Output: .0001100110011001100110011001100

or using recursion:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void fractobin(double frac, int digits);  

//==========================================================
int main()
{   
    cout <<".";

    fractobin(.1, 1);   

    return 0; 
}
//==========================================================

void fractobin(double frac, int digits)
{
    int intpart;
    if (digits >=32 || frac==0.)
    {
        return;  
    }
    else
    {   
        frac = frac * 2;
        intpart = frac; 

        cout << intpart;

        fractobin(frac - intpart, ++digits);  
        return; 
    }
}
```